# Parsing JSON using C# [Uncertain Object name]

Tags: c#, json

I'm going to parse the JSON data to class using C# and Newtonsoft.Json. But the JSON data is a little bit different than usual. 
Here is the JSON data sample:

```
{
    "ip_addresses": [
        "192.168.1.1"
     ],
    "ptr": {
        "192.168.1.1": "www.example.com"
    }
}
```

So the problem is **the IP in ptr changes due to the IP in ip_addresses**. I've successfully parsed ip_addresses data into the List. But I don't know how to do next with the List stored IP addresses.

```
class Server
{
    public string hostname { get; set; }
    public List<string> ip_addresses { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        string ip_set = string.Empty;
        foreach (string ip in ip_addresses)
        {
            ip_set += string.Format("{0} ", ip);
        }
        return string.Format("{0} {1}\n", hostname, ip_set)
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //json data is from the web response
        string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Server server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Server>(responseContent);

        Console.WriteLine(server);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Have a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing the `ptr` is not an array.
Then the following property might work

```
public Dictionary<string,string> ptr {get; set;}
```

If it is an array, then make it `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`

I'm on mobile, haven't checked it. Please verify

**Update**  : forgot to add
Access it using `ptr["ipAddress"]`